# How to test wepages/apps for slower speed inviroments

Tags: optimization, testing

How can i test webpage/app rendering for slow speed connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Fiddler web debugger - it has a feature to simulate slow modem speeds.

Answer (score 0):

What you're concerned with is what is actually going over the wire.  A tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) will help you understand how much data is being transmitted.  You can then work to whittle it down to as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)'s net console will tell you what each page is downloading, how much and how long its taking.  Tools like [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) and [Google Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) will give you suggestions about how to speed up the page both loading and rendering.